# C reverse rows in array

Tags: c, arrays

i have matrix represented as 1d array.
e.g. size of array is w*h where w is width a h is height,
lets say that matrix is of size 4*4

```
unsigned int new = (w*h)-w;
  unsigned int old = 0;
  for (unsigned int a=0; a< h; a++)
  {
    for (unsigned int b =0; b< w; b++)
    {
      data[new] = input[old];
      old++;
      new++;
    }
    new -= w*2;
  }
```

It works great and flip my array upside down(vertically), but i do not know what i should change in the code to flip array horizontally
- it will be some small change but i cannot see it

change array to 2d is possible, but `data` is of type struct
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please produce a [mre] and state expected and actual behavior

Comment: You're iterating variables `a` and `b` but you never use them in the loop. What's the point of doing that?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to write an example. i know it is strange. i used it to print indexes of cells in array, now i do not use it, it can be changed in one for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: it would have been better, if you wrote more descriptive: current input, current output and desired output. I guess, your code does this:

```
`input` array

 0  1  2  3 
 4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 

`data` array

12 13 14 15 
 8  9 10 11 
 4  5  6  7 
 0  1  2  3
```

I guess, what you want to get is:

```
 3  2  1  0 
 7  6  5  4 
 11 10 9  8
 15 14 13 12
```

Just by writing it, you see that, you just need to reverse each row. So, you need to reverse each w element of your `input` array (as each `w` elements represent one row). I do not see need to write code solution of this (it is even easier the code you have already).